# how i can trigger aop around method from another class manually

Tags: java, aop

i have this configuration in application xml

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect id="ruleAspect" ref="ruleInterceptor">
        <aop:pointcut expression="@within(....)" id="servicePointcut" />
        <aop:around pointcut-ref="servicePointcut" method="intercept"/>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

and if user trigger any action related my rules, that code runs

```
public Object intercept(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable  {
    ...
    ...
    for (Rule rule :ruleList) {
       rule.doApply(pjp);
    }
}
```

and this code call rule class doApply method

```
public class Rule1 {

    @Override
    protected Object doApply(ProceedingJoinPoint invocation) {
        ...
        ...
    }

}
```

now, my question is that how can i trigger doApply method from another class manually with pjp parameter. i do not create pjp object because it is interface. is there anyway to call it?

Comment: There is insufficient information in your question. Please update it into an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Incoherent code snippets are not helpful to those whom you expect help from. Help your helpers, make the problem reproducible.

Comment: @kriegaex, i do not understand you exactly. please tell me that which part is insufficient. i want to trigger `intercept(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp)` or `doApply(ProceedingJoinPoint invocation)` method manullay from another class.

Comment: What was unclear about [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I cannot copy your code into my IDE, run it and see where your problem is. I also would like to understand why anyone would want to manually call an aspect's advice. User _Daij-Djan_ is right to frown upon such practice. Which problem are you trying to solve? You only explain _how_ you think it should be solved. Your code neither shows the problem nor the way you have tried to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that this is how you should think of aspects. they get invoked by the runtime and aren't meant to be manually callable.

Best dont even think of aspects as classes and methods at all.

---

what I would do to 'workaround this' is put the relevant logic from the aspect method into a static helper class method that you can then share between aop and manual invocation